# Has anyone ever drawn a football field in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Has anyone ever drawn a football field in latex? I know that could seem like a strange request. But I'm looking for a package that allows me to draw a football field.

[image: football field]

Comment: You'll probably have to do it by hand, it's very unlikely that a package could do that. Do you know TiKz ?

Comment: This can be drawn any packages capable to draw lines, squares and circles, and coloring them. For example`pstriks` and `TikZ` amount of them.

Comment: Didn't we have this question before? (I guess this is from 2016, so maybe that was it.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just for fun:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, ducks}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\newcommand{\croacia}[3]{
\begin{scope}[shift={#3}, xscale=-.4, yscale=.4]
\duck
\path[preaction={fill=red}, pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=white] \duckpathjacket;
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=5mm]wing) {#1};
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (1.1,-.22) {#2};
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\france}[3]{
\begin{scope}[shift={#3}, scale=.4]
\duck[jacket=blue]
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=5mm]wing) {#1};
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (1.1,-.22) {#2};
\end{scope}
}

\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\newcommand\area[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, transform shape, rotate=#2]
\node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[%    
    every node/.style={draw=white, very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
]
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

%\draw (contour.south west) grid (contour.north east);

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}
\end{scope}

\croacia{23}{Subasic}{(1.25,4.25)}
\croacia{3}{Strinic}{(2.6,7.2)}
\croacia{21}{Vida}{(2.3,5.3)}
\croacia{6}{Lovren}{(2.3,2.9)}
\croacia{2}{Virsalijko}{(2.6,1)}
\croacia{11}{Brozovic}{(3.5,4.25)}
\croacia{4}{Perisic}{(4.5,7.2)}
\croacia{7}{Rakitic}{(4.5,5.25)}
\croacia{10}{Modric}{(4.5,3)}
\croacia{18}{Rebic}{(4.5,1)}
\croacia{17}{Mandzukic}{(5.6,4.25)}

\france{1}{Lloris}{(10.75,4.25)}
\france{2}{Pavard}{(9.5,7.2)}
\france{4}{Varane}{(9.5,5.3)}
\france{5}{Umtiti}{(9.5,2.9)}
\france{21}{Lucas}{(9.5,1)}
\france{13}{Kante}{(8.5,6)}
\france{6}{Pogba}{(8.5,2.3)}
\france{10}{Mbappe}{(7,7)}
\france{7}{Griezman}{(7.8,4.25)}
\france{14}{Matuidi}{(7,1.5)}
\france{9}{Giroud}{(6.4,4.25)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some comments:

The code for the football field is from [Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292457/1952).

I've copied player names (and positions) from Spanish newspapers which doesn't show correct spelling for Croacian/French players. Please fill free to correct them or let me know the correct spelling.

**Update:** `marmot` suggested a `tikzmarmots` version. Here it is.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}

\newcommand{\croacia}[3]{ \begin{scope}[shift={#3}, scale=.5] \marmot \path[preaction={fill=red}, pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=white] (1.35,0.71) .. controls (1.35,0.41) and (1.17,0.37) .. (0.92,0.37) .. controls (0.69,0.37) and (0.48,0.41) .. (0.48,0.71) .. controls (0.48,1.01) and (0.67,1.26) .. (0.91,1.26) .. controls (1.15,1.26) and (1.3 5,1.01) .. (1.35,0.71) -- cycle; \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (0.95,0.82) {#1}; \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (1.1,-.22) {#2}; \end{scope} }

\newcommand{\france}[3]{ \begin{scope}[shift={#3}, scale=.5] \marmot[body=brown!80!yellow] \path[fill=blue] (1.35,0.71) .. controls (1.35,0.41) and (1.17,0.37) .. (0.92,0.37) .. controls (0.69,0.37) and (0.48,0.41) .. (0.48,0.71) .. controls (0.48,1.01) and (0.67,1.26) .. (0.91,1.26) .. controls (1.15,1.26) and (1.3 5,1.01) .. (1.35,0.71) -- cycle; \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (0.95,0.82) {#1}; \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at (1.1,-.22) {#2}; \end{scope} }
\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\newcommand\area[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, transform shape, rotate=#2]
\node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[%    
    every node/.style={draw=white, very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
]
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

%\draw (contour.south west) grid (contour.north east);

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}
\end{scope}

\croacia{23}{Subasic}{(0.25,4.25)}
\croacia{3}{Strinic}{(1.6,7.2)}
\croacia{21}{Vida}{(1.3,5.3)}
\croacia{6}{Lovren}{(1.3,2.9)}
\croacia{2}{Virsalijko}{(1.6,1)}
\croacia{11}{Brozovic}{(2.5,4.25)}
\croacia{4}{Perisic}{(3.5,7.2)}
\croacia{7}{Rakitic}{(3.5,5.25)}
\croacia{10}{Modric}{(3.5,3)}
\croacia{18}{Rebic}{(3.5,1)}
\croacia{17}{Mandzukic}{(4.6,4.25)}

\france{1}{Lloris}{(10.75,4.25)}
\france{2}{Pavard}{(9.5,7.2)}
\france{4}{Varane}{(9.5,5.3)}
\france{5}{Umtiti}{(9.5,2.9)}
\france{21}{Lucas}{(9.5,1)}
\france{13}{Kante}{(8.5,6)}
\france{6}{Pogba}{(8.5,2.3)}
\france{10}{Mbappe}{(7,7)}
\france{7}{Griezman}{(7.8,4.25)}
\france{14}{Matuidi}{(7,1.5)}
\france{9}{Giroud}{(6.4,4.25)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**2nd Update**: I almost forgot `tikzpeople`.

I've been unable to customize Croatian shirt. If you know how to do it, please let me know or feel free to edit the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\newcommand{\croacia}[4][]{%
\begin{scope}[font=\small\sffamily, text=black!70!red]
    \node[person, minimum size=.8cm, anchor=center, shirt=red, #1] (#3) at #4 {#3};
    \path (#3.center)--(#3.south) node[midway]{#2};
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\france}[4][]{%
\begin{scope}[font=\small\sffamily, text=black!70!red]
    \node[person, minimum size=.8cm, anchor=center, mirrored, shirt=blue, #1] (#3) at #4 {#3};
    \path (#3.center)--(#3.south) node[midway]{#2};
\end{scope}
}

\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\newcommand\area[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, transform shape, rotate=#2]
\node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[%    
    every node/.style={draw=white, very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
]
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

%\draw[yellow,thin] (contour.south west) grid (contour.north east);

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}
\end{scope}

\croacia[shirt=orange]{23}{Subasic}{(.5,4.5)}
\croacia{3}{Strinic}{(2,8)}
\croacia{21}{Vida}{(1.8,6)}
\croacia{6}{Lovren}{(1.8,3)}
\croacia{2}{Virsalijko}{(2,1)}
\croacia{11}{Brozovic}{(2.7,4.5)}
\croacia{4}{Perisic}{(4,7.5)}
\croacia{7}{Rakitic}{(4,5.5)}
\croacia{10}{Modric}{(4,3.5)}
\croacia{18}{Rebic}{(4,1.5)}
\croacia{17}{Mandzukic}{(5.2,4.5)}

\france[shirt=yellow]{1}{Lloris}{(11.5,4.5)}
\france{2}{Pavard}{(10.2,8)}
\france{4}{Varane}{(10.2,6)}
\france{5}{Umtiti}{(10.2,3)}
\france{21}{Lucas}{(10.2,1)}
\france{13}{Kante}{(8.8,6.5)}
\france{6}{Pogba}{(8.8,2.5)}
\france{10}{Mbappe}{(7.5,7.5)}
\france{7}{Griezman}{(8,4.5)}
\france{14}{Matuidi}{(7.5,1.5)}
\france{9}{Giroud}{(6.8,4.5)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot Yes, but I could only use it for referees, tikzmarmots don't wear customizable shirts like ducks ;-)

Comment: @marmot It's done. Thank you for your command.

Comment: Why are the Croates running away from the French? ;-). Do you know the famous football ducks in the middle of the tikzducks christmas extravaganza https://vimeo.com/246256860?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now they run against the French (I hope they will do it ;-)). Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: Simply fantastic!

Comment: It could have been ducks against marmots.

Comment: @yo' Yes, but who are ducks and who marmots? I didn't want to start a war ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah, well, can ducks be the biggest European duck-eaters? :)

Comment: Now I need a CTAN package where I can draw football fields,and add the list of players and TiKz will put the name of the players. I'm not sure how to handle different formations (4-4-2 or 3-5-1-1), but you guys are smarter than me.
If the same package can draw baseball, hockey, basketball, and... American _football_, then I will seriously start writing the sport almanac, so the future me becomes rich.

Answer (score 77):

This is my version of it. I used the official measurements then divided them by 10 and switched from meters to centimeters (otherwise you'd need a really *huge* piece of paper to print it on).

I have included a command `\showmeasures` that will print the measures (the real ones).

### Output

*Regular*

[image]

*With measures*

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}

\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw=white, very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
    every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
}

\newcommand\area[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, transform shape, rotate=#2]
\node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand\showmeasures{%
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={draw=none,fill=field, inner sep=2pt, sloped}}
    \draw[black, {Latex}-{Latex}] ($(contour.north west)+(0,.5)$) -- ($(contour.north east)+(0,.5)$) node[midway] {\textbf{Sideline:} min 90m - max 120m};
    \draw[black, {Latex}-{Latex}] ($(contour.south west)+(-.6,0)$) -- ($(contour.north west)+(-.6,0)$) node[midway] {\textbf{Goal line:} min 45m - max 90m};
    \draw[black, -{Latex}] (penalty0) --++ (-15:0.915cm) node[midway, above, font=\scriptsize, fill=none, yshift=2pt] {r = 9.15m};
    \draw[black, {Latex}-{Latex}] ($(small0.south east)+(-.2,0)$) -- ($(small0.north east)+(-.2,0)$) node[midway,above, fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {18.32m};
    \draw[black] ($(small0.north west)+(0,.2)$) -- ($(small0.north east)+(0,.2)$) node[midway, above, font=\scriptsize, fill=none, xshift=3pt] {5.50m};
    \draw[black] (contour.south east) --++ (135:1mm) node[anchor=south east] {r = 1m};
    \draw[black, {Latex}-{Latex}] ($(big180.south east)+(-.5,0)$) -- ($(big180.north east)+(-.5,0)$) node[midway,above, rotate=180,fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {40.32m};
    \draw[black, {Latex}-{Latex}] ($(big180.south west)+(0,.2)$) -- ($(big180.south east)+(0,.2)$) node[midway,above,fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {16.50m};
    \draw[black] (contour.east) --++ (-11mm,0) node[midway,above, fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {11m};
    \node[font=\small, rotate=-90, yshift=5mm] at (goal180) {\textbf{Goal:} 7.32m $\times$ 2.44m};
    \draw[black, -{Latex}] (contour.center) --++ (0:0.915cm) node[midway, above, fill=none,font=\scriptsize, yshift=2pt] {r = 9.15m};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}

\showmeasures
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course Italians are more knowledgeable than Spaniards about soccer. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'm more of a TikZ fan than I am of soccer though. :P

Comment: @egreg Wait, I thought we were talking about *football* :)

Comment: Cool! Can you add circles/something to represent players in a formation and their names?  If so, it'd be a complete package

Comment: This kinda thing http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/rules_and_equipment/4197518.stm

Comment: @innisfree It wouldn't be hard. :D

Comment: @innisfree So you convinced me and now I'm almost done with the command to show the team formation. :P There are a couple of things I need to fix first, but it's there.

Comment: Why are the dimensions in those weird units? ;)

Comment: @JosephWright: _Everybody_ knows the max sideline length should be 14173,2 barleycorns! `:)`

Answer (score 36):

Adjust next code to correct dimensions:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand{\halfcourt}{
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,6);
\draw (0,1.5) rectangle ++(1.75,3);
\draw (0,2) rectangle ++(0.5,2);
\draw (0,2.5) rectangle ++(-0.1,1);
\draw (0.1,0) arc (0:90:.1);
\draw (0.1,6) arc (0:-90:.1);
\draw[fill] (1.25,3) circle (1pt);
\draw (5,3.8) arc (90:270:.8);
\begin{scope}
\clip (1.75,0) rectangle ++(2,6);
\draw (1.25,3) circle (1cm);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=green}, show background rectangle]

\halfcourt
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm, xscale=-1]
\halfcourt
\end{scope}
\draw[fill] (5,3) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could even have used symmetry four times instead of two `;-)`

Comment: @Clément So long time wanting to use symmetry and it's not good enough.  :-)

Comment: I think that the grass needs watering!

Comment: Too much water, too much water! Have a look at [http://latexcolor.com/](http://latexcolor.com/) to pick a nice green (for instance, `\definecolor{green(html/cssgreen)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}`). And now the lines needs to be in white!

Comment: For the green: `green!50!black`.

Comment: @ryuk : the best way to thank Ignassi for his / her answer is to mark it as accepted. [See here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/34551) if you don't know how to do that.