# What has been your most complicated TikZ drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, big-list

Share your most complex TikZ drawing and learning out of it.

Comment: Not sure how suitable this question is for this site. It is quite broad and does not have a definitive answer (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). http://www.texample.net/ has a collection of complex (and maybe also not so complex) TikZ drawings.

Comment: @moewe you can find a lot of such questions here on the site. I am not the only one. If that's the case all such questions must be deleted.

Comment: It is true that this site is very lenient with (some) [tag:big-list] questions, but I feel that the current formulation "your most complicated" is just *too* subjective.

Comment: None of my TikZ drawings are complex since I was able to make them. Some TikZ drawings seem very complex to realize for me, but as they were made by others, I can not share them.

Comment: This question is off-topic because [every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @EJoshuaS One could also argue it's okay because it "invite[s] sharing experiences over opinions."

Comment: @siracusa No, definitely not. See also: [Real Questions have Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). This falls under the category of "chatty, open-ended questions" and "mindless social fun," not a "practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this is on topic.  Also, one should aim for simplicity, not complexity.

Answer (score 49):

Inspired by Raaja's answer.
This is the standard [rotating snakes](http://www.psy.ritsumei.ac.jp/~akitaoka/rotsnakee.html).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \draw(-10,-10)rectangle+(20,20);
    \foreach\x/\y in{
        -1/ 1,  0/ 1,  1/ 1,
        -1/ 0,  0/ 0,  1/ 0,
        -1/-1,  0/-1,  1/-1,
          -.5/ .5, .5/ .5,
          -.5/-.5, .5/-.5
    }{
        \begin{scope}
            \tikzset{shift={(\x*6.6,\y*6.6)},xscale=(-1)^(\x+\y)}
            \pgflowlevelsynccm
            \foreach\j in{1,...,15}{
                \draw[line width=6mm,
                    dash pattern={on13.408ptoff13.408pt},
                    dash phase=\j*13.408pt]
                    circle(3);
                \draw[line width=6mm,white,
                    dash pattern={on13.408ptoff13.408pt},
                    dash phase=(\j+1)*13.408pt]
                    circle(3);
                \foreach\i in{1,...,20}{
                    \tikzset{rotate=\i*18+\j*9}
                    \fill[yellow!80!black]
                        (3,0)ellipse[x radius=3mm,y radius=1.5mm];
                    \tikzset{rotate=9}
                    \fill[blue]
                        (3,0)ellipse[x radius=3mm,y radius=1.5mm];
                }
                \tikzset{scale=.81818}
                \pgflowlevelsynccm
            }
        \end{scope}
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tex capacity exceeded for me.

Comment: @BPP Try to reduce `\foreach\j in{1,...,15}`. This loop is filling the center of the circle, which is not really necessary.

Answer (score 27):

This is not the most complicated drawing I have ever coded<sup>1</sup> but certainly the proudest picture I have ever had. That is the Ti*k*Zified<sup>2</sup> version of the most well-known picture ever – the [*Mona Lisa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa)!

[image]

The code (2.43 MB) is too long to be pasted here. You can see it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joulev/TikZ-figures/master/Mona%20Lisa/main.tex).

---

<sup>**1** | In fact, you can see well that this picture is not made by me. It is generated via [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). However, this is certainly the most complicated picture ever compiled in my computer and not made by anyone else (i.e. I got it <s>without any human help</s> with the help (or the idea) of Leonardo da Vinci only).</sup>

<sup>**2** | I stole this word from [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot). I hope he will give me the permission to use the word once he reads my answer.</sup>

Comment: “not made by anyone else (i.e. I got it without any human help)” — a certain Leonardo might claim a little share of the credit…  (+1, lovely example)

Answer (score 25):

I have to repost this one (details [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347014/28808)):

[image]

Most PDF viewers can't render it and the code is a mess, but it's certainly complicated  (856 lines of complicated).

Answer (score 25):

About a thousand lines of code, grabbing data from a bunch of external files and plotting stuff. The code is a mess but adaptable enough to display different data sets. Also came across some really strange bugs while working on it (such as: loading in large tables of data into Ti*k*Z may overlook a particular column until the document is compiled a second time or the column afterwards is also loaded.)

[image]

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 22):

This was complicated when I did it. Now it's more large than difficult or complicated. The original illustration is from "The Illustrated Network: How TCP/IP Works in a Modern Network" by Walter Goralski.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.symbols,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

\def\monitor{--+(6mm,0mm)--+(5mm,2mm)--+(3mm,2mm)--+(2mm,4mm)--+(5mm,4mm)--+(5mm,11mm)--+
(-5mm,11mm)--+(-5mm,4mm)--+(-2mm,4mm)--+(-3mm,2mm)--+(-5mm,2mm)--+(-6mm,0mm)--cycle}
\def\display{++(3mm,5mm) --++(0,5mm)--++(-6mm,0mm)--++(0mm,-5mm)--cycle}
\def\casa{--++(5mm,0mm)--++(0,7mm)--++(2mm,0mm)--++(-7mm,4mm)
--++(-7mm,-4mm)--++(2mm,0mm)--++(0mm,-7mm)--cycle}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
host/.style={draw, text width=3.5cm, fill=orange!10,font=\sffamily\small, align=left},
falshost/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=8mm},
router/.style={draw, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=blue!20, align=center},
etiqueta/.style={font=\sffamily\small, align=center}]


\begin{scope}
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2mm,row sep=2mm] {
    \node[host] (bsdclient) {
        em0: 10.10.11.177\\MAC: 00:0e:0c:3b:8f:94\\(Intel\_3b:8f:94)\\IPv6: fe80::20e:cff:fe3b:8f94}; \&
    \node[host] (lnxserver) {
        eth0: 10.10.11.66\\MAC: 00:db:b7:1f:fe:e6\\(Intel\_1f:fe:e6)\\IPv6: fe80::2d0:b7ff:fe1f:fee6}; \&
    \node[host] (wincli1) {
        LAN2: 10.10.11.51\\MAC: 00:0e:0c:3b:88:3c\\(Intel\_3b:88:3c)\\IPv6: fe80::20e:cff:fe3b:883c}; \&
    \node[host] (winsvr1) {
        LAN2: 10.10.11.111\\MAC: 00:0e:0c:3b:87:36\\(Intel\_3b:87:36)\\IPv6: fe80::20e:cff:fe3b:8736};\\[4mm]
    \node[falshost] (sbsdclient) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (slnxserver) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (swincli1) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (swinsvr1) {}; \\
};

    \node[fill=gray!30, inner sep=0pt, rectangle, rounded corners=4mm,fit=(sbsdclient)  (swinsvr1)] (lan1) {Ethernet LAN Switch with Twisted Pair-Wiring};
    \node[below,anchor=north east] at (lan1.south east) {\textbf{LAN1}};
    \draw (bsdclient) -- (sbsdclient);
    \draw (lnxserver) -- (slnxserver);
    \draw (wincli1) -- (swincli1);
    \draw (winsvr1) -- (swinsvr1);

    \foreach \a in {bsdclient, lnxserver, wincli1, winsvr1}
    {
        \fill[gray!30] ([yshift=1mm]\a.north) \monitor;
        \fill[white] ([yshift=1mm]\a.north) \display;
        \path (\a.north) ++(0mm,12mm) node[above] {\textbf{\a}};
    }

    \node[router,anchor=north] (CE0) [below = of lan1] {CE0\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.0.1}};
    \draw (lan1)--(CE0);
    \path (CE0.east)++(2mm,0mm) node[anchor=west,align=left,font=\sffamily\small] (tCE0)  {fe-1/3/0: 10.10.11.1\\
MAC= 00:05:85:88:cc:db\\(Juniper\_88:cc:db)\\IPv6: fe80:205:85ff:fe88:ccdb};
    \node[text width=2cm,align=center] () at (bsdclient|-CE0) {Los Angeles\\Office};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=16cm]
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2mm,row sep=2mm] {
    \node[host] (bsdserver) {
        eth0: 10.10.12.77\\MAC: 00:0e:0c:3b:87:32\\(Intel\_3b:87:32)\\IPv6: fe80::20e:cff:fe3b:8732}; \&
    \node[host] (lnxclient) {
        eth0: 10.10.12.166\\MAC: 00:b0:d0:45:34:64\\(Dell\_45:34:64)\\IPv6: fe80::2b0:d0ff:fe45:3464}; \&
    \node[host] (winsvr2) {
        LAN2: 10.10.12.52\\MAC: 00:0e:0c:3b:88:56\\(Intel\_3b:88:56)\\IPv6: fe80::20e:cff:fe3b:8856}; \&
    \node[host] (wincli2) {
        LAN2: 10.10.11.222\\MAC: 00:02:b3:27:fa:8c\\\mbox{\null} \\IPv6: fe80::202:b3ff:fe27:fa8c};\\[4mm]
    \node[falshost] (sbsdserver) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (slnxclient) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (swinsvr2) {}; \& 
    \node[falshost] (swincli2) {}; \\
};

    \node[fill=gray!30, inner sep=0pt, rectangle, rounded corners=4mm,fit=(sbsdserver)  (swincli2)] (lan2) {Ethernet LAN Switch with Twisted Pair-Wiring};
    \node[below,anchor=north east] at (lan2.south east) {\textbf{LAN2}};
    \draw (bsdserver) -- (sbsdserver);
    \draw (lnxclient) -- (slnxclient);
    \draw (winsvr2) -- (swinsvr2);
    \draw (wincli2) -- (swincli2);

    \foreach \a in {bsdserver, lnxclient, winsvr2, wincli2}
    {
        \fill[gray!30] ([yshift=1mm]\a.north) \monitor;
        \fill[white] ([yshift=1mm]\a.north) \display;
        \path (\a.north) ++(0mm,12mm) node[above] {\textbf{\a}};
    }

    \node[router,anchor=north] (CE6) [below = of lan2] {CE6\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.6.1}};
    \draw (lan2)--(CE6);
    \path (CE6.east)++(2mm,0mm) node[anchor=west,align=left,font=\sffamily\small] (tCE6)  {fe-1/3/0: 10.10.12.1\\
MAC= 00:05:85:8b:bc:db\\(Juniper\_8b:bc:db)\\IPv6: fe80:205:85ff:fe8b:bcdb};
    \node[text width=2cm,align=center] () at (bsdserver|-CE6) {New York\\Office};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(8cm,-9cm)}]
\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2.5cm,row sep=1.5cm]  {
    \& \node[router] (P9) {P9\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.9.1}}; \& \& \node[router] (P7) {P7\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.7.1}}; \& \\
    \node[router] (PE5) {PE5\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.5.1}}; \& \& \& \&  \node[router] (PE1) {PE1\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.1.1}}; \\
    \& \node[router] (P4) {P4\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.4.1}}; \& \& \node[router] (P2) {P2\\\textbf{lo0: 192.168.2.1}}; \& \\
};
\draw (P9.east) -- (P7.west) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start] {so-0/0/1\\79.2}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end] {so-0/0/1\\79.1};
\draw (P9.south) -- (P4.north) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start,align=right,left] {so-0/0/3\\49.2}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end,align=right,left] {so-0/0/3\\49.1};
\draw (P4.east) -- (P2.west) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start] {so-0/0/1\\24.2}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end] {so-0/0/1\\24.1};
\draw (P7.south) -- (P2.north) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start,align=left,right] {so-0/0/3\\27.2}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end,align=left,right] {so-0/0/3\\27.1};
\draw (P9.south east) -- (P2.north west) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\29.2}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\29.1};
\draw (P4.north east) -- (P7.south west) 
    node[etiqueta,very near start,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\47.1}  
    node[etiqueta,very near end,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\47.2};
\draw (PE5.east) -- (P9.west) 
    node[etiqueta,near start,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\59.1}  
    node[etiqueta,near end,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\59.2};
\draw (PE5.east) -- (P4.west) 
    node[etiqueta,near start,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\45.2}  
    node[etiqueta,near end,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\45.1};
\draw (P7.east) -- (PE1.west) 
    node[etiqueta,near start,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\17.2}  
    node[etiqueta,near end,sloped] {so-0/0/2\\17.1};
\draw (P2.east) -- (PE1.west) 
    node[etiqueta,near start,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\12.2}  
    node[etiqueta,near end,sloped] {so-0/0/0\\12.1};
\draw[dashed,very thick,gray] (PE5.north) -- (CE0.south) 
    node[etiqueta,pos=.15,sloped,black] {ge-0/0/3\\50.1}  
    node[etiqueta,pos=.85,sloped,black] (ge502) {ge-0/0/3\\50.2};
\draw[dashed,very thick,gray] (CE6.south) -- (PE1.north) 
    node[etiqueta,pos=.15,sloped,black] (ge162) {ge-0/0/3\\16.2}  
    node[etiqueta,pos=.85,sloped,black] {ge-0/0/3\\16.1};
\end{scope}

    \fill[green!50] (bsdclient|-P9) \casa;
    \node[xshift=1cm,align=center,anchor=south west] at (bsdclient|-P9) {\textbf{Wireless}\\\textbf{in home}};
    \draw[dotted] (bsdclient|-P9) -- (PE5.north) node[above,sloped,pos=0.5] {DSL Link};
    \draw[dashed] (bsdclient.west|-ge502.west)--(winsvr1.east|-ge502.west);
    \draw[dashed] (bsdserver.west|-ge162.east)--(wincli2.east|-ge162.east);

    \node[cloud,draw,aspect=2,cloud puffs=15,text width=3cm, align=center,anchor=north,fill=violet!20] (internet) at (PE1|-P2.south)  {\textbf{Global Public}\\\textbf{Internet}};
    \draw (P4) |- ([yshift=-3mm]internet) node [pos=0.6,above] {AS 65459};
    \draw (P2) |- ([yshift=3mm]internet) node [pos=0.7,above] {AS 65127};

    \node[text width=5cm, align=left, font=\sffamily\small,anchor=south west] at (bsdclient.west|-internet.south) {Solid rules = SONET/SDH\\Dashed rules = Gigabit Ethernet\\\emph{Note}:All links use 10.0.x.y\\addressing. Only the last\\two octets are shown.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Some other Tikz figures are already here:

- [Karnaugh Maps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140581/1952)
- [Soccer/Football teams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440501/1952)

Comment: I would like to bring to your notice that the above url "Soccer/Football teams" points to a post containing Karnaugh maps.

Comment: @GermanShepherd Corrected! Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 22):

I was once a note-taker for disabled students, and for the final lecture I ended the last set of notes with a TikZ version of the Looney Tunes ending screen. First time using `\foreach`, and the `decorations` library.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, shadows}
\newfontfamily\looney[]{That's Font Folks!}
\definecolor{darkblueOuter}{RGB}{1,11,23}
\definecolor{darkblueInner}{RGB}{1,18,37}

\begin{document}
\looney
\fontsize{68pt}{1em}\selectfont

\thispagestyle{empty}

% Manual centering
\vspace*{-4.25cm}
\hspace{-8cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3, every shadow/.style={opacity=1,fill=blue!10!black}]
  \foreach \l in {13.8,12.8,...,2.8} {
    \path[circular glow={shadow scale=1.03}, shading=radial, inner color=yellow!80!white, outer color=red!50!black] (0, 0) circle (\l cm);
  }

  \path[circular glow={shadow scale=1.03}, shading=radial, inner color=blue!25!black, outer color=darkblueOuter] (0, 0) circle (2.8cm);

  \node (b) at (-6, -2) {};
  \node (e) at (7, -0.5) {};
  \draw[decoration={text along path, text color=white, text={That's all Folks!}}, decorate] (b) to[bend left=15] (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Looney Tunes]

Comment: For the sake of “meta” of this community wiki, I hope this answer stays at the end. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I learned how to use loops in `TikZ` for the first-time ever.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471465/drawing-concentric-circles-with-alternating-colors-by-means-of-foreach-in-tikz/471466#471466
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=none,minimum size=20, line width = 8pt}]
  \foreach \x in {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}
\node [mystyle,  minimum size = \x cm, color =red!70]  (2) at (0, 0) {};
  \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18, 20}
\node [mystyle,  minimum size = \x cm, color =yellow!50]  (2) at (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: This image is kind of hypnotising :)

Comment: @samcarter I know right? Therefore, I am proud of this image as my first looped creation :D

Comment: (you already have my +1) Your diagram should be considered to be illegal for the harm it did to my eyes :))

Comment: @JouleV Good luck looking into that. I just inserted that image closing my eyes :D

Comment: @samcarter, not like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479386/14757)

Comment: @Sigur that's better than this ;)

Comment: @Sigur I would answer your comment, but I cannot stop staring at those wheels :)

Comment: @samcarter specially when we try to focus on a circle center...

Answer (score 11):

Reposting something I originally created for the TeX-mas 2018 event, and adapted for the Groundhog Day 2019 event. It shows a [Ulysses](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Papilio_ulysses_ambiguus_Rothschild%2C_1895.JPG) butterfly flapping its wings intermittently, with a corresponding shadow that moves in the same way.

Easily the most complex image I've ever made with tikz. It took a lot of effort to recreate all its markings and get the shape of the wings right. In the process I increased my understanding and familiarity with tikz tenfold. I was really proud of the result, and how much I improved.

[image: Ulysses butterfly made by Ulysses]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
%\documentclass[export]{standalone}
% All design and code created by Ulysses. Please credit me if you use a significant portion of this anywhere.

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\halfwing}[1]{
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=#1]
    % Lower Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1.4) -- (-2,1.4) .. controls (-4,0.8) .. (-4.3,0.2) .. controls (-4.48,0.08) .. (-4.5,-0.15) .. controls (-4.9,-0.5) and (-4.9,-0.7) .. (-4.7,-0.9) .. controls (-4.7,-1) .. (-4.6,-1.1) .. controls (-4.9,-1.8) .. (-4.2,-2) -- (-4,-2.4) .. controls (-4.1,-3) .. (-3.6,-3.1) -- (-3.25,-3.7) .. controls (-3.5,-4.5) .. (-4.1,-5.4) .. controls (-4.2,-5.9) and (-3.6,-5.9) .. (-3.5,-5.4) .. controls (-3.55,-5.1) and (-3.4,-4.8) .. (-3,-4.1) -- (-2.6,-4.1) .. controls (-2.35,-4.35) .. (-2,-4.2) .. controls (-1.75,-4.6) and (-1.25,-4.6) .. (-1.25,-3.90) .. controls (-0.9,-4) .. (-0.6,-2.8) -- (-0.3,-1) -- (0,0.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black,rounded corners=1mm] (-0.8,-3) .. controls (-0.5,-2) .. (-0.30,-0.95){[rounded corners=0mm] .. controls (-0.15,-0.3) .. (-0.05,0.45) -- (-0.05,0.7)} -- (-0.7,0.4) .. controls (-0.9,-2) .. (-0.8,-3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!60!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.1,-2.9) .. controls (-1.4,2) and (0.5,2) .. (-1.1,-2.9);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.6,-2.8) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (0,-0.1) .. (-1.6,-2.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.1,-2.6) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.1,-2.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.6,-2.2) .. controls (-0.3,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.6,-2.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3,-1.7) .. controls (0.1,3.7) and (0.1,-0.1) .. (-3,-1.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.4,-1.2) .. controls (0.77,3) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.4,-1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.6,-0.6) .. controls (0.77,2.2) and (0.77,-0.5) .. (-3.6,-0.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.5,0) .. controls (0.77,1.8) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.5,0);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!10!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.5,0.7) .. controls (0.77,2) and (0.77,0) .. (-2.5,0.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,0.6) -- (-0.05,0.9) .. controls (-4,-0.5) and (-1.5,-2) .. (-0.05,0.6);

    % Upper Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2) [rounded corners=7mm] parabola[bend at end] (-6,6) -- (-5,1) -- (0,1);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!20!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4,3.5) .. controls (3,-1) and (-2,4) .. (-4,3.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue,draw=black] (-4.1,3) .. controls (3.9,-0.5) and (-2.1,4) .. (-4.1,3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!80!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,2.5) .. controls (4,-0.2) and (-2.2,3.5) .. (-4.2,2.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.8) .. controls (4,0.3) and (-2.2,3) .. (-4.2,1.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.2) .. controls (4.05,0.9) and (-2.2,2.4) .. (-4.2,1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.85) -- (-0.05,1.80) .. controls (-6.5,6.5) and (-2,5.5) .. (-0.05,1.85);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!10!cyan!,bottom color=blue!50!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.8) -- (-0.05,1.4) .. controls (-7.5,5.5) and (-2,5) .. (-0.05,1.8);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\butterfly}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Guide lines
    %\draw[step=1cm,lightgray,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    %\draw[step=0.2cm,lightgray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\draw[step=1cm,cyan,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\end{scope}

    % Background
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!20!white!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (0,0) circle (10cm);

    % Text
    \draw (0,-7) node {\Huge Papilio Ulysses};
    \draw[decoration={text along path,text={Design and code created by Ulysses.},text align={center}},decorate,rotate=90] (0,0) circle (9.8cm);

    % Shadow
    \begin{scope}[transparency group,xshift=0.4cm,yshift=-0.4cm,opacity=0.2]
        % Antenna
        \draw[thick,black] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
        \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
        \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
        \draw[thick,black] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
        \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
        \end{scope}
        % Body
        \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2.5mm] (0,2.5) -- (0.35,2.5) -- (0.45,1.5) -- (0.45,0) -- (0.25,-2) -- (-0.25,-2) -- (-0.45,0) -- (-0.45,1.5) -- (-0.35,2.5) -- (0,2.5);
        % Head
        \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2mm] (0,3) -- (0.45,3) -- (0.2,2.3) -- (-0.2,2.3) -- (-0.45,3) -- (0,3);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black,thick] (-0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black,thick] (0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);
        % Wings
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
            \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=#1]
            % Lower Wing
            \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1.4) -- (-2,1.4) .. controls (-4,0.8) .. (-4.3,0.2) .. controls (-4.48,0.08) .. (-4.5,-0.15) .. controls (-4.9,-0.5) and (-4.9,-0.7) .. (-4.7,-0.9) .. controls (-4.7,-1) .. (-4.6,-1.1) .. controls (-4.9,-1.8) .. (-4.2,-2) -- (-4,-2.4) .. controls (-4.1,-3) .. (-3.6,-3.1) -- (-3.25,-3.7) .. controls (-3.5,-4.5) .. (-4.1,-5.4) .. controls (-4.2,-5.9) and (-3.6,-5.9) .. (-3.5,-5.4) .. controls (-3.55,-5.1) and (-3.4,-4.8) .. (-3,-4.1) -- (-2.6,-4.1) .. controls (-2.35,-4.35) .. (-2,-4.2) .. controls (-1.75,-4.6) and (-1.25,-4.6) .. (-1.25,-3.90) .. controls (-0.9,-4) .. (-0.6,-2.8) -- (-0.3,-1) -- (0,0.2);
            % Upper Wing
            \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2) [rounded corners=7mm] parabola[bend at end] (-6,6) -- (-5,1) -- (0,1);
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.35cm]
            \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-#1]
            % Lower Wing
            \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1.4) -- (-2,1.4) .. controls (-4,0.8) .. (-4.3,0.2) .. controls (-4.48,0.08) .. (-4.5,-0.15) .. controls (-4.9,-0.5) and (-4.9,-0.7) .. (-4.7,-0.9) .. controls (-4.7,-1) .. (-4.6,-1.1) .. controls (-4.9,-1.8) .. (-4.2,-2) -- (-4,-2.4) .. controls (-4.1,-3) .. (-3.6,-3.1) -- (-3.25,-3.7) .. controls (-3.5,-4.5) .. (-4.1,-5.4) .. controls (-4.2,-5.9) and (-3.6,-5.9) .. (-3.5,-5.4) .. controls (-3.55,-5.1) and (-3.4,-4.8) .. (-3,-4.1) -- (-2.6,-4.1) .. controls (-2.35,-4.35) .. (-2,-4.2) .. controls (-1.75,-4.6) and (-1.25,-4.6) .. (-1.25,-3.90) .. controls (-0.9,-4) .. (-0.6,-2.8) -- (-0.3,-1) -- (0,0.2);
            % Upper Wing
            \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black,thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2) [rounded corners=7mm] parabola[bend at end] (-6,6) -- (-5,1) -- (0,1);
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

    \end{scope}

    % Antenna
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \end{scope}

    % Body
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2.5mm] (0,2.5) -- (0.35,2.5) -- (0.45,1.5) -- (0.45,0) -- (0.25,-2) -- (-0.25,-2) -- (-0.45,0) -- (-0.45,1.5) -- (-0.35,2.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,2.24) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.24cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.75) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.75) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.25) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.75) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.25) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.74) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.24cm);

    % Head
    \shadedraw[inner color=black!60!white!,outer color=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2mm] (0,3) -- (0.45,3) -- (0.2,2.3) -- (-0.2,2.3) -- (-0.45,3) -- (0,3);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (-0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);

    % Wings
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    \halfwing{#1}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.35cm]
    \halfwing{-#1}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,scale=1]{13}
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe[1.5]
    \butterfly{1}
\end{animateinline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not too complicated but it was the last one I draw.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\raio{.75}
\def\N{10}
\coordinate (Z\N) at (1.5*\N,0);
\node[thick, circle, minimum size=2*\raio cm, draw] (C\N) at (Z\N){};
\foreach \x in {1,...,\N}{
    \coordinate (Z\x) at (1.5*\x,0);
    \fill (Z\x) circle (1pt);
    \node[circle, minimum size=1.5*\raio cm] (C\x) at (Z\x){};
    \ifnum \x=1
        \draw[thick] (C1.north) to[out=30,in=150] (C1.east) to[out=-30,in=-10] (C1.south) to[out=170,in=-10] (C1.west) to[out=170,in=210] (C1.north)node[above]{$V_n(x)$};
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (C10) to[out=-60,in=-60]node[below]{$f^{-n}$} (C\x.south);
        \draw[-latex] (C1.east)  to[out=35,in=140]node[below]{$f^n$} (C\N);
    \fi
    \ifnum \x=2
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$f(x)$};
        \draw[-latex] (C10) to[out=-65,in=-60]node[above]{$f^{-(n-1)}$} (C\x.south);
    \fi
    \ifnum \x=5
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$f^j(x)$};
        \draw[-latex] (C10) to[out=-70,in=-60]node[above]{$f^{-j}$} (C\x.south);
    \fi
    \ifnum \x=8
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$f^{n-2}(x)$};
        \draw[-latex] (C10) to[out=-75,in=-60]node[below]{$f^{-2}$} (C\x.south);
    \fi
    \ifnum \x=9
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$f^{n-1}(x)$};
        \draw[-latex] (C10) to[out=-85,in=-60]node[above]{$f^{-1}$} (C\x.south);
    \fi
    \ifnum \x=\N
        \node[below] at (Z\x){$f^{n}(x)$};
    \fi
}

\draw (Z10) --node[above]{$\delta$} ($(Z\N)+(45:\raio cm)$);
\node (contraction) at ($(Z\N)+(-35:3*\raio cm)$){\normalsize contraction};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun purposes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \y in {0,10,...,110}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=orange,bottom color=yellow] (-2.2,-2.2) rectangle (2.2,2.2);
    \shade[ball color=black] (0,0) circle (.25);
    \foreach \x in {\y,\y+120,\y+240}{\shadedraw[left color=black,right color=gray] (\x:2) arc (\x:\x+60:2) -- (\x+60:.3) arc (\x+60:\x:.3) -- cycle;}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code gave me a sequence of images.

Comment: @BPP: I am surprised you said that.

Answer (score 5):

[I am in the process of making an overview of symmetric functions.](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/polynomialindex.htm)

For a quick overview how these relate to each other,
I made the following two tikz images:

[Relations graph](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/polynomial-graph-relations.pdf)
[Positivity graph](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/polynomial-graph-positivity.pdf)

Here is a small part of the relations graph.
Arrows indicate relations such as "is superset of", "specialize to", "is related via other transformation", etc.
[image: small part of graph of relationships between symmetric functions]